# How to fix missing instance of IO for a function constrained on MonadReader and MonadIO?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haskell-persistent

I have been trying to get a good understanding of [mtl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) by building a project using it in combination with [persistent](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent).

One module of that project has a function which uses [insertMany_](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.0/persistent-2.10.5.2/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:insertMany_)

```
service
  :: (MonadReader ApplicationConfig m, MonadIO m) =>
     ReaderT SqlBackend (ExceptT ApplicationError m) ()
service = insertMany_ =<< lift talkToAPI
```

Here `talkToAPI` can fail so the response is wrapped in `ExceptT`, its type is

```
ExceptT ApplicationError m [Example]
```

In short the `service`'s job is to talk to an API, parse the response and use `insertMany_` to store that response into a database.

The actual storage action is handled by [withPostgresqlConn](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.0/persistent-postgresql-2.10.1.2/Database-Persist-Postgresql.html#v:withPostgresqlConn)

```
withPostgresqlConn
  :: (MonadUnliftIO m, MonadLogger m) =>
     ConnectionString -> (SqlBackend -> m a) -> m a
```

---

Using `runReaderT` on my `service` function yields

```
ghci> :t runReaderT service
ghci> (MonadReader ApplicationConfig m, MonadIO m) =>
       SqlBackend -> ExceptT ApplicationError m ()
```

so to process this *I believe* I need to use `runExceptT` like this

```
runService :: ConnectionString -> IO ()
runService connStr = either print return
  =<< runStdLoggingT (runExceptT $ withPostgresqlConn connStr $ runReaderT service)
```

But I get these two errors

```
• No instance for (MonadUnliftIO (ExceptT ApplicationError IO))
        arising from a use of ‘withPostgresqlConn’

• No instance for (MonadReader ApplicationConfig IO)
        arising from a use of ‘service’
```

What could be the problem here? There has likely been an error on my part but I'm not sure where to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that [`ExceptT ApplicationError IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT) doesn't—and in fact can't—have an [`MonadUnliftIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-core-0.2.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Unlift.html#t:MonadUnliftIO) instance. Few monads have that instance: `IO` (the trivial case) and also `Identity` and `Reader`-like transformers over `IO`.

The solution is to "peel" the `ExceptT` constructor *before* passing `service` to `withPostgresqlConn`, not after. That is, passing a `SqlBackend -> m (Either ApplicationError ())` value instead of a `SqlBackend -> ExceptT ApplicationError m ()` value. You might get that by composing the function with [`runExceptT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:runExceptT).

---

We still have to select a concrete type for `m` so that it satisfies 
the `MonadReader ApplicationConfig m, MonadIO m` constraints required by `service` and also the `MonadUnliftIO m, MonadLogger m` constraints required by `withPostgresqlConn`. (Actually, we can forget about `MonadIO` because `MonadUnliftIO` implies it anyway).

In your code, you invoke `runStdLoggingT` and expect to get down to `IO`. That means that `m` is expected to be `LoggingT IO`. That's fine because [`LoggingT`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.0/monad-logger-0.3.32/Control-Monad-Logger.html#t:LoggingT) has a `MonadUnliftIO` instance, and of course a `MonadLogger` one. There's a problem though: what satisfies the `MonadReader ApplicationConfig` constraint? Where's the config coming from? That's the cause of the second error.

The solution is to make `m` something like `ReaderT ApplicationConfig (LoggingT IO)`. The `runService` function should take an additional `ApplicationConfig` parameter, and invoke `runReader` with the config before invoking `runStdLoggingT`.

---

A more general point is that monad transformers often have "passthrough" instances which say things like "if the base monad is an instance of typeclass C, then the transformed monad is also an instance of C". For example `MonadLogger m => MonadLogger (ReaderT r m)` of `MonadUnliftIO m => MonadUnliftIO (ReaderT r m)`. But such instances don't always exist for every transformer-typeclass combination.

Comment: In particular, `runService appConf connStr = either print return =<< (flip runReaderT appConf $ runStderrLoggingT $ withPostgresqlConn connStr $ runExceptT . runReaderT service)` should typecheck.